# Change GET to POST Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, get

I have an Opportunity model. When I click my "Create Opportunity" button in my new form view, my terminal says that I made a "GET" request. Furthermore, after I click it, it does not make any run any of my validation scripts nor does it create a new record. I used "rake routes" and saw that my new_opportunite route is a GET request:

new_opportunity GET    /opportunities/new(.:format)    opportunities#new

Does anyone know how I can change that route to make it a POST?

Thanks!!

rake routes:

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                  Controller#Action
          opportunities GET    /opportunities(.:format)                                     opportunities#index
                        POST   /opportunities(.:format)                                     opportunities#create
        new_opportunity GET    /opportunities/new(.:format)                                 opportunities#new
       edit_opportunity GET    /opportunities/:id/edit(.:format)                            opportunities#edit
            opportunity GET    /opportunities/:id(.:format)                                 opportunities#show
                        PATCH  /opportunities/:id(.:format)                                 opportunities#update
                        PUT    /opportunities/:id(.:format)                                 opportunities#update
                        DELETE /opportunities/:id(.:format)                                 opportunities#destroy
```

routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :test_users

  get 'profile/my_profile'

  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"

  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"

  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  root :to => "sessions#new"

  get 'view_submitted/submitted'

  get 'view_action_list/seven'

  get 'show_number/thirty'

  get 'show_number/sixty'

  get 'show_number/year'

  get 'view_retired/retired'

  resources :users
  resource :sessions

  get 'report/report_page'

  resources :opportunities do
    resources :activities
    resources :updates
    resources :contacts
    resources :links

  end
```

my form:

```
    <%= form_for(@opportunity) do |f| %>
      <% if @opportunity.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@opportunity.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this opportunity from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @opportunity.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>


      <table id="new_opp_form" style="width: 450px; background-color: white; border-style: none; border:1px orange;">
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Department</td>
            <td><%= f.select :department, [[],['DHS', 'DHS'], ['DOS', 'DOS'], ['FDIC', 'FDIC'], ['HUD', 'HUD'], ['SEC', 'SEC'], ['VA', 'VA']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Agency</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :agency %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Program Name</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :program_name %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Stage</td>
            <td><%= f.select :stage, [[],['Assessment', 'Assessment'], ['Pre-Proposal', 'Pre-Proposal'], ['Proposal', 'Proposal'], ['Subitted', 'Submitted'],['Retired', 'Retired']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Capture Manager</td>
            <td><%= f.collection_select(:capture_manager, User.all, :full_name,:full_name,{:prompt => true}) %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Program Description</td>
            <td><%= f.text_area :program_description %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>New or Re-recompete</td>
            <td><%= f.select :new_or_recompete, [[],['New', 'New'], ['Re-Compete', 'Re-Compete']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Incumbent</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :incumbent %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Current Contract Vehicle</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :curent_contract_vehicle %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>New Contract Vehicle</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :new_contract_vehicle %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Small Business Set Aside?</td>
            <td><%= f.select :sb_set_aside, [[],['Yes', 'Yes'], ['No', 'No']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Prime or Sub</td>
            <td><%= f.select :prime_or_sub, [[],['Prime', 'Prime'], ['Sub', 'Sub']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>NAICS</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :naics %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>RFI Date</td>
            <td><%= f.date_select :rfi_date, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>RFI Submitted?</td>
            <td><%= f.select :rfi_submitted, [[],['Yes', 'Yes'], ['No', 'No']] %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Est. RFP Date</td>
            <td><%= f.date_select :est_rfp_date, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Est. Full Value</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :est_full_value%></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Est. Workshare (%)</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :est_workshare %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>P(win) %</td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :p_win %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background-color: white">
            <td>Govwin ID</td>
            <td> <%= f.text_field :govwin_id %></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %> 
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: problem not in your routes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a form to create this? If so you should be using `[form_for][1] @var_name` which will create a form and when *submitted* it will `POST` to the correct path.  You can also optionally specify `method: :post` for the link I believe, but this is bad practice because links should be `GET` requests and not `POST`'s.

Comment: I just added my form... I believe it is in the format you mentioned.

Comment: Forms should always POST when creating a new record by default.  If you open up chromes dev tools and watch the network request when you submit does it show a post?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things in your question:

`When I click my "Create Opportunity" button in my new form view, my terminal says that I made a "GET" request`

Forms by default make a `post request` if you have something like

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  #your fields
<% end %>
```

this will generate

```
<form action="/people" class="new_person" id="new_person" method="post">
  //your fields
</form>
```

---

`Furthermore, after I click it, it does not make any run any of my validation scripts nor does it create a new record. I used "rake routes" and saw that my new_opportunite route is a GET request`

When you *submit your form you are not routed to your new action but you are routed to the create action of your resources controller*

If you look at your output of rake routes

```
POST   /opportunities(.:format)      opportunities#create
new_opportunity GET    /opportunities/new(.:format)
```

Your second route `new_opportunity GET    /opportunities/new(.:format)` will be called when your **form renders on your browser window**, you can *check it on your browsers address bar* also and your first route `POST   /opportunities(.:format)      opportunities#create` is the one which will be called when **you submit your form** and it *will take you to opportunities#create*

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct route your looking at. 
Either you did not configure your routes correctly or your looking at the wrong route.
The route `new_opportunity GET /opportunities/new(.:format) opportunities#new` is the route that renders the form.
The route that posts the form looks like this;

```
opportunities POST       /opportunities(.:format)                               opportunities#create
```